# I need query last poll (question & choice) as form

Tags: django

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """This class represents a question. It can have 2 or more options."""
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = 1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, max_length = 200)

class Choice(models.Model):
    """This represents an answer to the Question, and has a foreignkey to it"""
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.TextField()
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

I want query last question and it's choice Im try but can't get last as form

Comment: could u post, what have u tried so far!

Comment: Im tried

 def last_q(request):
        return render_to_response('poll/last.html', {
            'last_q':  Question.objects.all()[:1]
}
)
but I can't get last question And choice as form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the last item you can do something like:

```
q = Question.objects.order_by('id').reverse()[0]
```

and to get the choices:

```
choices = q.choice_set.all()
```

To sum-up, this is how your view should look like:

```
def last_q(request): 
  return render_to_response('poll/last.html', { 'last_q': Question.objects.order_by('id').reverse()[0] } )
```

and this is your template:

```
{% for c in last_q.choice_set.all %}
 <input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{ c.id }}" />{{ c.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

something like that!

Comment: I didnt understood yet why you need a form?! could u explain better! and edit your main question?!

Comment: Sorry My english languge is not good 
I meant form (template) for vote 
like this
    <form action="." method="post">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <input type="RADIO" name="choices"value=""/>
                                                    
    </li>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Answer Poll" name="submit" />
    </form>

Comment: Another question ^_^ I want get title write this {{c.title}} but don't show

Comment: Have u created that new field in the model?! if yes! have this field been created in your db? check your table in the DB! I would guess that U added the field to the model but the field is not in the DB Table. this Usually happen because Django dont change tables that are already created! to make it work! drop your DB, create again and  run 'syncdb'! another way to make this work without dropping is using South: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/index.html

Comment: No I don't created any new field "title" its in Question Table look at my main post

Comment: so why are you trying to get title from 'c', which is a choice instance! you have to get it from last_q!!like this: {{ last_q.title }}

Comment: it's work thanks again 
I have to read book about django well